# Karate - How to get results from 'called' features to print

Tags: karate, spring-boot-test

I am trying to stage some data into my database by calling another scenario. However, when i run my 'get' call it comes up empty. So my thought was, I want to print the result of my call. When I run the below I get nothing, and if I remove the '.result' and just print 'x', it just prints the name of the feature.

Ideally though, I wouldn't do that at all and the feature I'm calling would just print stuff directly to the html report. Is there any way to get it to do that?

```
      Background:
    * url baseurl+'/graphql'
 
    * configure headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

  Scenario: get desks
  * def x = call read ('Mutations.feature@add-desk') 
  * print x.result
 
   Given text query =
    """
    {
    getDesks{
    deskId
    name
    groupName
    trader{
      traderId
      initials
      userId
    }
  }
}
    """
    And request { query: '#(query)' }
    When method post
    Then status 200
    # pretty print the response
    * print 'response:', response

    * match response.data.getDesks[*].name contains ['FX Desk', 'Muni Desk']
```

---

```
  Background:
    * url baseurl
    * path '/graphql'
 
    * configure headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

  @add-desk
  Scenario: Add a desk to the database
   Given text query =
    """
    mutation {
  createDesks(
    desks: [
      { name: "FX Desk" }
      { name: "Muni Desk" }
    ]
  ) {
    name
    groupName
    deskId
  }
}

    """
    And request { query: '#(query)' }
    When method post
    Then status 200
    # pretty print the response
    * print 'response:', response

    * match response.data.createDesks[0] contains { groupName: 'GBI' }
    * def result = response
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as we know, `called` features should `print`. Of course there can be bugs. So please follow this process, and ideally contribute code: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue